# Initializing a Spring Session Bean using an HttpRequest (using annotations)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I am trying to build (or augment) a webapp that uses Spring beans, initialized with annotations. I have a bean that I need to initialize, but the bean needs an `HttpServletRequest` to properly initialize (it's a user identity bean).

I've browsed the documentation, and I've seen pieces of what I need, but the pieces don't seem to assemble into a complete solution.

Pseudo-example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserBean userBean() {
        // initialize with HttpRequest somehow?
    }
}

@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Resource
    UserBean userBean;

    @RequestMapping(value="/userId", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUserInfo() {
        // do stuff with the initialized user bean here
    }
}
```

Note that there are multiple controller classes, so I'm not sure which may be encountered first.

I see two possible things that could be done:

1. Initialize the bean in a lazy way in the `MyConfig` class. But I'm not sure how to access the `HttpServletRequest` object.
2. Inject the bean into the session in the `getUserInfo()` method. But then every method in the class might need the same initialization logic, and I'm not sure how to inject the initialized UserBean into the session so that other controllers would access the same UserBean.

Any help/recommendations/etc. would be appreciated

Comment: Remember that if the solution is hackish, it is a strong indicator that it is wrong.  `HttpServletRequest` is a request object for a reason, have you considered passing it as a parameter to the `UserBean`'s method instead?

Comment: The UserBean object is actually initialized using the HttpServletRequest object, e.g.  UserBean user = UserBean.create(request);

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the piece you are missing is the "[spring scoped beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-request)" feature.

Basically, scoped beans are beans that are managed (created/destroyed) by spring so you don't need to worry about that. You also don't have to worry about initialization. Spring handles it for you.

Plese try this. Add the `Scope` definition to your `UserBean` and inject the `HttpServletRequest` into your UserBean

```
@Bean
@Scope("request")
public UserBean userBean() {
    return new UserBean();
}

@Component
public class UserBean {

  @Inject
  HttpServletRequest request;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
    // Access request object to initialize your object
  }
}
```

**Edit**

If you cannot modify the UserBean you can get the request & initialize the bean in the java config. For example:

HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder

```
@Bean
@Scope("request")
public UserBean userBean() {
   HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
   return new UserBean(request);
}
```

Comment: The UserBean object in the actual code (or more specifically, its analogue) is in a library that I don't have control over. I forgot to mention that. So I can't annotate it with a Bean or Scope.

Comment: This seems like the way to solve it, but would this put the UserBean only in the request scope? Or would it persist it?

Comment: @EdwardSwing scopes have predefined lifecycles. request scope data only lives as long as the request is alive. Persistence is a complete different story. In that case you would need to integrate a data storage into your application in order to save your data

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to create some kind of a server-side session storage.
If that is the case, your best choice may be using the session handling that comes with your Servlet environment. According to the Spring docs, a `@RequestMapping`-annotated method can take an argument of the type `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`.
On this object, you can use the `getSession()` method to get the user's session or generate a new one if none exists. Your `UserBean`-class will not be a bean anymore, just a normal object. You can store it in the session using the `setAttribute(String, Object)`- and read it using the `getAttribute(String)`-method.
This session object should then contain the same `UserBean` object no matter what controller you are in.